# Check if an overloading method exist in device iOS platform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There are 2 "writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum" methods in ALAssetsLibrary Class:

```
- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef 
                            metadata:(NSDictionary *)metadata 
                     completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

(available on iOS 4.1+)

```
- (void)writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:(CGImageRef)imageRef 
                         orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)orientation
                     completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteImageCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

(available on iOS 4.0+)

I am using the 1st one (need iOS 4.1) in my code and it will crash on iOS 4.0 device. I am trying to use `respondsToSelector` to check which method is supported, however looks like the selector only check the method name, not the parameters.

I read some suggestions and feel it might not good by purely check on OS version, so is there anything similar to respondstoselector that can help me solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by parameters? And how have you implemented it now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misunderstand the Objective-C method naming system. The selector **is the combination of all** `foo:bar:baz:` **combined**.
So, in this case, there is no method called `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`. The first one is, as a selector, corresponds to

```
@selector(writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)
```

and the second one is

```
@selector(writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:)
```

In your code, check whether the first selector is available or not, as in

```
if([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)]){
      ....
}
```

This should distinguish whether the first one is available or not.

Answer (score 7):

These methods have different names, so you can test them separately.

```
if ([assetsLibrary respondsToSelector:
     @selector(writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:)]) {
    // Now you can safely use this method.
}
```

If you wanted to test the other one you would use `@selector(writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can then differentiate them with os version. How about it?